# How to remember active tab using jQuery.cookies and custom jQuery tabs code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have written this code to make quick tabs. I need a way to remember active tab after refreshing page.

Here is my basic HTML code:

```
<ul class="dashboard_tabs">
    <li><a href="#" rel="tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="dashboard_body" id="tab1">

</div>

<div class="dashboard_body" id="tab2">

</div>

<div class="dashboard_body" id="tab3">

</div>

<div class="dashboard_body" id="tab4">

</div>
```

I use rel relations to display the correct tab with this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.dashboard_body').css({display: 'none'});
    jQuery('.dashboard_tabs a:first').addClass('current');
    var rel = jQuery('.dashboard_tabs a.current').attr('rel');
    jQuery('#'+rel).show();

    jQuery('.dashboard_tabs a').click(function(){
        jQuery('.dashboard_tabs a').removeClass('current');
        jQuery('.dashboard_body').hide();
        jQuery(this).addClass('current');
        var rel = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
        jQuery('#'+rel).show();
    });
});
```

How can I use jQuery cookies to remember active tab?

Answer (score 1):

Just create/update the cookie in your click function

```
$.cookie('active_tab', rel);
```

You can then easily read the active tab from the cookie in your ready function and do whatever you want with CSS or alike.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question: [How to set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery). You can use `jquery-cookie` plugin for easy manipulate with cookies. On `document ready` read `rel` from cookies and set correct tab. On `click event` just save `rel` in cookies.